# Express.js cookie-parser middleware doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have a very simple express server which logs the request and sets a cookie. My Express Server sets the cookie correctly (documents.cookie shows it in the console + my logger middleware shows it on the server under req.headers.cookie), but my body-parser middleware doesn't create the req.cookie attribute (its undefined).

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var app = express();

//bodyparser
app.use(express.json());

//cookieparser
app.use(cookieParser());

//logger
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.method);
   console.log(req.path);
   console.log('query: ' + req.query.code)
   console.log('params: ' + req.params.code);
   console.log('cookie: ' + req.cookie);
   console.log("header cookie: " + req.headers.cookie);
   next()
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.cookie('name', 'express').send('cookie set'); //Sets name = express
});

app.listen(80);

console.log("Server listen on port 80");
```

Comment: `cookie-parser` sets the parsed cookies to `req.cookies`, not `req.cookie`.

Comment: Thank you. 4 years of coding and I simply forget a „s“.